# Boostrap Intellisense not working in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

I want VS code auto-suggestion of bootstrap class names. But it isn't working for me.
I have already installed below two extensions and tried others, but none seems to be working.

[image]

What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do any suggestions work?

Check VS Code settings, Inline Suggest should be enabled.
Also you should close and reopen VS Code after installing HTML CSS Support
If you are using remote css files, add this:

```
"css.styleSheets": [
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
]
```

To the `settings.json`.

You can replace the link with the one you're using.

Comment: Yes, checked. Everything is set. But still there isn't any suggestion on bootstrap classnames

Comment: Try clicking ctrl+space with the cursor between quotation marks of the class attribute, it should activate IntelliSense. Does it recognize bootstrap class names that way?

Comment: No. I did the same, but it still didn't recognize. Also I am not using remote CSS files

Comment: I've read IntelliSense might have some issues when using libraries like React. 
You could try checking some libraries designes specifically for React.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ZackLittke-Smith.reactcssautocomplete

Comment: there is an update. I have opened my previous repositories, where the bootstrap suggestions work correctly. It is the only problem with the current repository.

Comment: Thats weird. Are the other repositories React based too?
Not an elegant solution, but in that case I'd clone the repository (if its stored on git server of any kind) to a different directory, and check it there.

Comment: yes, that is also react based. Only difference is that the current repo is typescript based, while the other is fully js.